# How to show the path in the title bar of Files (Nautilus)

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, files

Scenario: I have several Files windows open. One's open to /home/me/workspace/abc, one's open to /opt/Tomcat/webapps/abc, and one's open to /etc/abc.

I want to work in the /opt/Tomcat/webapps/abc window.

But when I look at the three windows on the desktop, I cannot tell at a glance which is which. Why? Because each has a title of "abc".

Desired Solution: Configure Files (Nautilus) to display the full current working directory in the title bar.

Obstacle: I can't find a way to configure this.

Is there a way to do this? I'd edit the Nautilus source code and rebuild it if I had to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Steps I've taken

- I looked into the Nautilus preferences just in case you missed something. You know. Just in case.
- I looked into the hidden preferences of Nautilus using dconf-editor, in case the option is there but just hidden away.
- I searched online for a few minutes for solutions
- I glanced at the source code of the version of Nautilus included in Ubuntu 14.04, to see if I could achieve this in 5 minutes with no prior familiarity with the code

#### Conclusion

- Nautilus has no built in option to achieve this, not even hidden ones
- You could of course patch and rebuild nautilus to do this for yourself, but you would need some prior experience with C, and give yourself some time to make sure your solution is correct, because the [latest tutorial I could find](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1009550) is severely outdated and might not be entirely correct anymore. I concluded that this would take me more than 5 minutes (probably a few hours), so I did not do it.
- However, all is not lost, because there exists a fork of Nautilus called Nemo, which is in the repositories (`sudo apt-get install nemo`) and does exactly what you want.

Comment: You, sir, win the Internet. Add steps to make Nemo the default file manager (http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/set-nemo-as-default-file-manager-in.html) and I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 0):

May not be what you really want but under Preferences, than Display, and Icon Captions you can choose location.

Its not the title bar but it's under the files.

Comment: I just realised you said you on 14.04 but but what I did was on 15.04

Comment: Your solution means opening and looking inside each window in turn, which is exactly what I'd hoped to avoid. You're changing the caption for an individual file displayed within the file manager, not the caption for the file manager window.  
  
I don't have any trouble seeing the current file manager path if I open the window; it's in the address bar near the top of the window.